# What's the best time to install SSL certificate on a WordPress blog?

Tags: wordpress, https, security-certificate

I have created a new WordPress blog and just added a post on it. I want to install SSL certificate on this blog.

What's the best practice to install SSL certificate? Is it before WordPress installation or after WordPress installation or doesn't it matter?

Comment: The content management system  you are running (WordPress) should have nothing to do with your SSL.  Your security certificate is installed directly on your web server, probably Apache, IIS, or Nginx.

Comment: I'm not sure SSL is important for blogs which are all articles. SSL is important when a visitor is submitting private information, such as in a form. If you are just displaying blog posts, don't worry about SSL.

Answer (score 2):

I would add an SSL straight away. You get a slight ranking boost and provides a secure connection for your visitors.

You can use a quick solution such as [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com) to add this at the domain level, or even [Really Simple SSL](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/) wp plugin.

---

**In The News**

In July 2018, Google will be making it visible on the web browser if websites are not secure. It has the potential to drive people off your site. [Read More >](https://www.theverge.com/2018/2/8/16991254/chrome-not-secure-marked-http-encryption-ssl)

Comment: I would add that LetsEncrypt is free, and any overhead of SSL is normally marginal [source](http://istlsfastyet.com).